# Keep count in temporary variable for later use in query

Tags: postgresql, count

I have used WITH query for this as below

```
WITH my_count AS 
(
    SELECT count(emp_name) 
    FROM   employee 
    WHERE  joined_date < '2017-11-30'::Date 
    AND    region = 'UK'
)
INSERT INTO my_summary (property_key, month, property_value) 
VALUES ('count des', '2016-11-30', my_count);
```

But this gives me an error as below:

> ERROR:  column "my_count" does not exist
>   LINE 4: ...rty_value) VALUES ('count des', '2016-11-30', my_co...
>                                                                   ^
>   SQL state: 42703
>   Character: 244

So How do we keep count in a temporary variable for later use? If this is not possible, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to base your `insert` statement on a select:

```
WITH my_count (cnt) AS (
  SELECT count(emp_name) 
  FROM employee 
  WHERE joined_date < '2017-11-30'::Date AND region = 'UK'
)
INSERT INTO my_summary (property_key, month, property_value) 
select 'count des', '2016-11-30', cnt
from my_count;
```

Or use a scalar select:

```
WITH my_count (cnt) AS (
  SELECT count(emp_name) 
  FROM employee 
  WHERE joined_date < '2017-11-30'::Date AND region = 'UK'
)
INSERT INTO my_summary (property_key, month, property_value) 
values
('count des', '2016-11-30', (select cnt from my_count));
```

Also, both methods could be implemented without a CTE. Taking the first query as an example, the variation without a CTE would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_summary (property_key, month, property_value) 
SELECT 'count des', '2016-11-30', count(emp_name) 
FROM employee 
WHERE joined_date < '2017-11-30'::Date AND region = 'UK';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a MATERIALIZED VIEW

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_summary
AS SELECT
  count(emp_name) AS property_value,
  'count des'     AS property_key,
  '2016-11-30'    AS month
FROM employee
  WHERE joined_date < '2017-11-30'::Date
  AND region = 'UK';
```

In fact, at that you can be even more abstract and summarize everything.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_summary
AS SELECT
  region,
  date_trunc('month',joined_date)    AS month
  count(emp_name)                    AS property_value,
  'count des'                        AS property_key,
FROM employee
GROUP BY region, date_trunc('month', joined_date);
```

Then you can just `REFRESH VIEW my_summary;` when you require an updated copy. A few notes,

- You probably don't want `count()`, but instead `avg()`.
- My suggested method puts the day at the first day of the month, yours randomly chose the 30th day. Some months don't have 30 days, so that's not safe.